# Can we make Google Maps Javascript Geocoding API v3 return a custom identifier in the response?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a bunch of addresses (array of strings) that I write to a page variable and onready, make a `geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, callback)` call for each of those addresses. I also draw a table of the addresses originally loaded. Not all of these will be a "valid"***** address so not all of them will have markers on the map.

I want to update the table to show only the addresses which are mapped and want to be able to highlight the corresponding row in the table when a marker is clicked on. What I need is, some kind of connection between the addresses that I originally had and those that were marked.

I was hoping I would be able to pass a custom identifier value that I can pass to `geocoder.geocode()` which would get returned in `results` which I can use in the `callback` function

Any ideas?

*****valid is a simplified term for some business conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use `Function Closure`

```
function my_geocoder(address) {
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

       //do something with the geocoder responce here. 
       //you also still have access to the `address` variable to do what you will. 
    });
}

...

for(....) {
    my_geocoder(address);
}
```

It can be done without function closure, but this pattern makes it easy. (other methods it can be easy to get tripped up). (and if being pedantic its not actully function closure that enables this, its variable scope, but again combining with closure, avoids some pitfalls)